# Downloading and writing a text file onto tmpfs is slower than writing to disk, why?

Tags: shell-script, wget, disk, io, tmpfs

I have a tmpfs named `/rtmp/` that has 1GB of RAM allocated to it on Ubuntu OS.

Using a bash script, I am testing to see if it is faster using to write a small text file to the hard disk or if it is faster to write to this RAM drive `/rtmp/`.

**Bash Script writing to hard disk**

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="http://some.website/some.txt"

wget -O ~/current/axis_tmp ${URL}

cat ~/current/axis_tmp | grep "^pattern" | tail -n 1 | awk -F',' '{printf("%.0f\n", $3)}' | sed 's/ //g' > ~/current/tmp.txt

sed -i 's/^/X,/' ~/current/tmp.txt
sed -i 's/$/,Y/' ~/current/tmp.txt

exit 0
```

**Bash Script writing to tmpfs**

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="http://some.website/some.txt"

wget -O /rtmp/axis_tmp ${URL}

cat /rtmp/axis_tmp | grep "^pattern" | tail -n 1 | awk -F',' '{printf("%.0f\n", $3)}' | sed 's/ //g' > /rtmp/tmp.txt

sed -i 's/^/X,/' /rtmp/tmp.txt
sed -i 's/$/,Y/' /rtmp/tmp.txt

exit 0
```

After running the `time` command, I have the following results:

**Writing to disk**

```
real    0m0.554s
user    0m0.022s
sys     0m0.003s
```

**Writing to tmpfs**

```
real    0m0.614s
user    0m0.023s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Why was it slower to write the text file to `tmpfs` than writing the file to the disk? Shouldn't the process time have been *faster* writing to the `tmpfs`?

Comment: Edit the question to include the script you used to test this. Micro benchmarking like this tends to run it a bunch of issues like caching. Single samples are also not useful, you need to use averages.

Comment: Hi @hardillb, I've updated the question to include the bash script

Comment: There are way too many moving parts in that script to test file access time. You could easily have way more than 1/10th  of second difference just in the wget before you look at anything else.

Comment: I don't see `/rtmp` being used anywhere in the script.

Comment: @muru, I have added the test bash script that writes to the `tmpfs`

Comment: @hardillb, after turning off `wget`, I now have the following file access times:

Comment: @hardillb Writing to disk: `real    0m0.015s, user    0m0.017s, sys     0m0.003s`

Comment: @hardillb Writing to tmpfs: `real    0m0.013s, user    0m0.013s, sys     0m0.005s`

Comment: Measuring any download-related thing is just _not possible_ for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: Plus, reading up the comments, after you've removed `wget` there is hardly any difference, is this question still valid or already invalidated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is not the proper way to test I/O. As [hardillb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/44275/hardillb) pointed out, some of them and there are a lot more. This is why there are dedicated tools for this. The best tool for this could be IMHO the [`fio`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fio). You can try it like this

```
fio --name=fio-rand-write --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --direct=0 --numjobs=4 \
--size=512M --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=16
```

You just `cd` to a folder in the partition you want to test, e.g. `/rtmp` and launch the command. Feel free to read its documentation or other threads here for more info.

Comment: Please avoid your stating your personal opinions like as this case, you have plainly said _"The best tool for this is..."_. Just avoid that in the future, nothing more, ok.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak: Thanks for the edit and I will leave it as it is. However, for the record, this was not my humble opinion, this is the opinion of **Linus Torvalds**. He said: **"Anything else is suspect"**. I can't quote the source because it was a google+ thread and Google+ is no longer available for consumers

Comment: Okay, now you managed to make me _feel strange_. For #1, Linus does not have anything related to our [U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) as far as I know. And #2, I don't care for Linus' insight in this topic, **I care for yours**. That is the sole reason you are meant to answer questions. If you merely want to put someone else's words into your answer, be sure to quote it with `>` and add a link for us to validate. Thank you and I really mean well, once you realize it, feel free to edit my answers ;)

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak: You are right. I got your point.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak: Yet you don't care for what he thinks the best tool for the job is?

Comment: @JohnHawthorne I fail to see how that is relevant, really.

Answer (score -1):

A script does an awful lot of work before/after doing the work requested (here writing a bit of data): need to start the shell program (presumably already in memory, not too big of a deal), initialize its's data area, locate, read and interpret startup file(s) (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` in your home, system wide ones, ...), read and interpret the commands given in those, read and interpret the commands in the script, run the programs called in turn, tear down everything afterwards. What you are measuring is mostly overhead, not the work itself.

Shell is for direct user interaction, and has some rudimentary facilities for programming (I often write one-liners an the fly to e.g. process several files in one swoop), you can write more substantial programs too (as long as performance isn't critical this is fine). But for serious scripting better use a language designed for the task, like Python, Perl or Raku. Neither scripting alternative is the right tool for serious benchmarking. At least not without a lot of care.